# GO : "SendUpdates" not working when using google calendar API

Tags: go, google-calendar-api

I'm using `GOLANG`.

I'm trying to use `google-calendar-API` to send notification to participants.

I tried some functions in the document of the `calendar` package which mentioned about sending notification via email. (e.g.: `SendNotifications` & `SendUpdates`)

But none of them worked.

I've attached attendees inside the `event` structure so those email owners can see the invitation at the calendar board themselves, but does not receive any email.

My part of code :

create event instant :

```
event := &calendar.Event{
        Summary:     "Google calendar test",
        Location:    "800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103",
        Description: "go hiking!",
        Start: &calendar.EventDateTime{
            DateTime: "2022-01-05T10:00:00",
            TimeZone: "Asia/Taipei",
        },
        End: &calendar.EventDateTime{
            DateTime: "2022-01-05T11:00:00",
            TimeZone: "Asia/Taipei",
        },
        Attendees: []*calendar.EventAttendee{
            &calendar.EventAttendee{Email: "TESTINGGMAIL@gmail.com"},
        },
}
```

insert events :

```
calendarId := "primary"
    event_notification := srv.Events.Insert(calendarId, event).SendUpdates("all")
    event, err = event_notification.Do()
```

Comment: I thought that your issue might be related to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/132000322 and https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79605242

Comment: I solved it by adding my attendee's email to the participant in the OAuth consent screen in google cloud platform! Thanks for providing ideas!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Comment: My pleasure sir!

Answer (score 0):

**[Solve]**

The answer for me is quite directly(and dumb).

Since I'm relying on the google cloud platform with their API( which the `publish status` of OAuth has been configured to be the "testing stage" by me ) , I think it requires the attendees to also be a `Test user` for all relative things to be done.

Simply enter your

```
Google cloud platform
->hit on the Navigation Menu at the left top
->API's & Services
->OAuth consent screen
```

and click on the `+ ADD USERS` under the `Test users` section,
then , type in the emails of attendees presenting in the project.